# EclipseLink MOXy @XmlPath support for axes/parent

Tags: xpath, jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

Are any of the following XPath expressions acceptable? Using version 2.3.1 of eclipselink

```
@XmlPath("../header/@type")
@XmlPath("/root/header/@type")
@XmlPath("parent::*/header/@type")
```

Basically this is in a class which repeats within the XML document (`/root/tag`), if that isn't clear I'll elaborate.

I'm trying to traverse up the tree rather than down. My other `@XmlPath` annotations are working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php)** does currently not support axes/parent.  If you are interested in this kind of support please enter an enhancement request:

- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=EclipseLink

It does support XPath like:

- @XmlPath(".") // Map to self node, useful when mapping two objects to same element
- @XmlPath("@foo") // Map to attribute
- @XmlPath("foo") // Map to element
- @XmlPath("foo[2]") // Map to 2nd occurence of
- @XmlPath("foo[@bar='Hello World']") // Map to foo element with bar attribute with value "Hello World"
- @XmlPath("ns1:foo/ns2:@bar") // Map to namespace qualified nodes

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/xpath-based-mapping-geocode-example.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/03/map-to-element-based-on-attribute-value.html

Comment: Any update on this? MOXy is really good, but for our team to push it, our project needs 'parent' and 'child' due to the complicated xml object in certain instances.

Comment: Wondering whether there are any updates on this (2 years after the last comment here) - I really appreciate MOXy but it feels a bit like an incomplete tool without supporting at least the ancestor axis ..