# Xpath annotation with a predicate

Tags: xml, xpath, predicate, moxy

First, I am new in Xpath. I have found plenty of samples that queries if an element exists ,using Xpath. But I could not manage to implement the sample that I want. My xml is like:

```
<a>
    <b>
        <c>xxx</c>
        <d>yyy</d>
    </b>
</a>
<a>
    <b>
        <d>zzz</d>
    </b>
</a>
```

And I only want the "a" items with both "c" and "d" exists. So I did this:

```
@XPath("a/b[boolean(c) and boolean(d)]")
private A a;
```

COuld someone please show me the right way to do it?

Thanks

Ali

Answer (score 1):

```
a[descendant::c and descendant::d]
```

selects `a` nodes with `descendant` nodes `c` and `d`.

Note that your XML sample is invalid as it lacks a root node (presumably it is just a sample, not your actual document...).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually I think it should be like this: a/b[//c and //b] . I have tried your way and mine but it still jaxb still gives all the "a" elements :(

Comment: it depends on how specific you want to be. You're specifying `c` and `d` nodes under `a/b` with your original query--your question only says that you want `a` nodes where both `c` and `d` are descendants. Your query in the comment won't work because `//` searches for any node under the root node--you want nodes that are descendants of `a`. If you have a specific output in mind, you need to state it clearly in your question.

Comment: u are right about the "a under b and c" thing and I have corrected it :) thx. I have used descendant but it brings no elements even there are suitable ones :( I do not know if it is because of the annotation

Comment: Does your XML validate? Have you tried the xpath using an online tester (e.g. http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html) and your actual XML? There are a number of possible problems if the XPath isn't working -- it might be nothing to do with the XPath itself. :\

Comment: As one tag of the OP mentions that moxy is used, axes like descendant:: etc won't work. See e.g. here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8404134/eclipselink-moxy-xmlpath-support-for-axes-parent and the still not resolved bug https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=365840

Comment: @matthias_h I haven't used moxy, but I suspected that might be why this wasn't working...

Comment: matthias_h I think that is my answer, thx my friends, thx @i-alarmed-alien

Comment: @Neron *maybe* XPath that doesn't contain axis will work in moxy : `a[b[c and d]]`