# jaxb moxy xpath preceding-sibling

Tags: xpath, jaxb, moxy

I have the following xml and for the life of me cannot get preceding-sibling or following-sibling to work.  I've tried these with no luck.

I would like to get the sibling just before the Category element that has name attribute that equals "sporting".  So it would be the Group element i want.  None of these work:

```
Transaction/Animals/Dog/Boxers/Boxer/Category[@name='sporting']/preceding-sibling::
Transaction/Animals/Dog/Boxers/Boxer/Category[@name='sporting']/preceding-sibling::[1]
Transaction/Animals/Dog/Boxers/Boxer/Category[@name='sporting']/preceding-sibling::Group
```

Cant even get previous boxer....none of these work.

```
Transaction/Animals/Dog/Boxers/Boxer[@name='Butch']/preceding-sibling::
Transaction/Animals/Dog/Boxers/Boxer[@name='Butch']/preceding-sibling::Boxer
Transaction/Animals/Dog/Boxers/Boxer[@name='Butch']/preceding-sibling::[1]
Transaction/Animals/Dog/Boxers/Boxer[@name='Butch']/preceding-sibling::[*]
```

--thanks

```
<Transaction>
    <Animals>
        <Dog>
            <Boxers>
                <Boxer id="46436">
                    <Transaction source="kennel"/>
                    <Category name="local"/>
                </Boxer>
                <Boxer name="Spike">
                    <Group id="456"/>
                    <Category name="sporting"/>
                </Boxer>
            </Boxers>
        </Dog>
        <Dog>
            <Location Storee="pet store"/>
            <Boxers>
                <Boxer id="345739">
                    <Submission Source="store"/>
                    <Category name="local"/>
                </Boxer>
                <Boxer name="Butch">
                    <Group id="123"/>
                    <Category name="sporting"/>
                </Boxer>
            </Boxers>
            <Additional>
                <EffectiveDate>2015-03-01</EffectiveDate>
                <ExpirationDate>2016-03-01</ExpirationDate>
            </Additional>
        </Dog>
    </Animals>
</Transaction>
```

Comment: Ok both of these work using http://www.utilities-online.info/xpath

But neither one works using Moxy's @XmlPath tag.  ARRRRGH!!!
[Transaction/Animals/Dog/Boxers/Boxer[@name='Butch']/preceding-sibling::*
Transaction/Animals/Dog/Boxers/Boxer[@name='Butch']/preceding-sibling::Boxer]

Answer (score 1):

Well, figured out that moxy doesn't do axis. Which is ridiculous.

[EclipseLink MOXy @XmlPath support for axes/parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8404134/eclipselink-moxy-xmlpath-support-for-axes-parent)